# How can I integrate MYOB APIs with Magic XPA?

Tags: myob, magic-unipaas

I am looking to integrate MYOB desktop services with Magic XPA 3.0. Can anyone help about this?

Answer (score 2):

How you approach this will depend on which MYOB product you are integrating with. Some versions of the desktop products will have an ODBC driver, others connect using a REST API.  Depending on connectivity and versions you may need keys or a developer account.

I'm not familiar with Magic XPA but you would need to ensure it has either ODBC connections (e.g. via a DSN) or JSON over HTTP (+ OAuth and custom headers for authentication).

The best next step is probably to contact the API developers support team at MYOB so they can help determine the best connectivity for your application.  The team have a contact form at the bottom of this page: http://developer.myob.com/contact/

Good luck!